# VSCode does not show Unity Intellisense, is there any fix for it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have been trying to setup Unity and VSCode for a couple days now and I believe I have tried everything under the sun to get intellisense to work. To be more clear of the problem, intellisense does not appear to show up when typing anything Unity related. Apart from looking for a fix to intellisense, is there anyway to check what version of mono, vscode, and omnisharp are installed? If extra info is needed, I can provide.

I am using an iMac 2011 running macOS Monterey, if more info needed just ask and I will provide.

I am truly stumped and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have downloaded both mono, omnisharp and all packages for .csproj. I have also made sure VSCode is set to my external script editor in Unity as well as setting API configurability is set to .Net Framework (I read on here that might help). So far the only problem I can assume is messing up intellisense is the omnisharp, I am unaware if omnisharp is properly download as I keep getting offered to download it when reloading or opening VSCode. I do however, believe I fixed the omnisharp as I recently download the latest version for it. I am honestly starting to believe that I just turned off intellisense without realizing it.

Comment: Apologies, I have gotten intellisense to work finally. I believe my problem was Omnisharp (at least it was the last problem I fixed).

Answer (score 4):

I will try to the best of my abilities to describe in depth of what I did in order to help any future unfortunate coders.

1. Set VSCode to External Script Editor in unity. (Go To **Unity > Preferences > External Tools** then select what IDE you are using.
2. While in External Tools, check all boxes under .csproj files and then regenerate project files.
3. Close Unity and open VSCode and then go to settings (**Code > Preferences > Settings**. Search for "Omnisharp:UseModernNet" uncheck that setting and if prompted, install any Omnisharp builds.
4. In setting still, search "Omnisharp: Path" and type in "Latest", you will probably be prompted to install a new Omnisharp again, install it.
5. After that, close and reopen VSCode through the dock or application folder. If it IntelliSense doesn't work, I suggest download mono if not already download. Again if not already download, you must download .Net SDK files.

I apologize if the answer is a bit sloppy, I am baffled that it works, after submitting the question, all I had to do was quit and reopen VSCode from the dock and it somehow just started working. Good luck to anyone with this problem, I hoped this helped. If anymore info is need or any questions feel free to message me and I'll help the best I can.

Comment: This solved it on my side, now that visual studio isn't supported on Mac anymore ... Life savior !

Comment: Looks like Microsoft picked up support for VS Code and Unity.  Using [this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/microsoft-previews-unity-extension-for-visual-studio-code.1468913/), you can use the Visual Studio Editor package in Unity and the Unity Extension in VSC.  Can even open code from the editor.